# AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster unreachable: dial tcp Timeout

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, terraform, helm

I configured EKS Cluster with Terraform, and used Helm to deploy ingress.
When I try to apply my Terraform configuration, it fails to create the ingress software because it fails to connect the EKS cluster.

**providers.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.3.7"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.49.0"
    }

    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "~> 2.16.1"
    }

    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "~> 2.8.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "main" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_name
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "main" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_name
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.main.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.main.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.main.token
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.main.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.main.certificate_authority.0.data)
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.main.token
  }
}
```

**vpc.tf**

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 3.19.0"

  name = "main"
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr

  azs = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, var.availability_zones_count)

  # https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/networking/subnets/#using-private-and-public-subnets
  private_subnets = [cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 0), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 1)]
  public_subnets  = [cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 2), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 3)]

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  single_nat_gateway = true

  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html
  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  tags = var.tags

  vpc_tags = {
    Name                                           = "${var.project}-vpc",
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-cluster" = "shared"
  }

  public_subnet_tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}-public-subnet",
    # https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/deploy/subnet_discovery/#common-tag
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-cluster" = "shared"
    # https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/deploy/subnet_discovery/#public-subnets
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb" = 1
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}-private-subnet"
    # https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/deploy/subnet_discovery/#common-tag
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-cluster" = "shared"
    # https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/deploy/subnet_discovery/#private-subnets
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb" = 1
  }
}
```

**eks.tf**

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 19.5.1"

  cluster_name    = "${var.project}-cluster"
  cluster_version = "1.24"
  subnet_ids      = module.vpc.private_subnets
  vpc_id          = module.vpc.vpc_id

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    first = {
      desired_capacity = 1
      max_capacity     = 2
      min_capacity     = 1

      instance_type = "t3.small"
      capacity_type = "ON_DEMAND"
      disk_size     = 20
      ami_type      = "AL2_x86_64"
    }
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack = "backend"
      Name  = "${var.project}-eks-cluster",
    }
  )
}

# Since the Ingress controller runs as Pod in one of your Nodes, all the Nodes should have permissions to describe, modify, etc. the Application Load Balancer.
resource "aws_iam_policy" "worker_policy" {
  name        = "worker-policy"
  description = "Worker policy for the ALB Ingress"

  policy = file("./resources/node-ingress-policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "additional" {
  for_each = module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups

  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.worker_policy.arn
  role       = each.value.iam_role_name
}

resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
  name       = "ingress"
  chart      = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  repository = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"
  version    = "1.4.7"

  set {
    name  = "autoDiscoverAwsRegion"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "autoDiscoverAwsVpcID"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = "${var.project}-cluster"
  }
}

module "eks-kubeconfig" {
  source  = "hyperbadger/eks-kubeconfig/aws"
  version = "2.0.0"

  cluster_name = module.eks.cluster_name
  depends_on   = [module.eks]
}
```

After ruuning `terraform apply` I get this error:

```
helm_release.ingress: Creating...
helm_release.ingress: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
helm_release.ingress: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
helm_release.ingress: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://<..>.gr7.***.eks.amazonaws.com/version": dial tcp 10.0.1.59:443: i/o timeout
│ 
│   with helm_release.ingress,
│   on eks-cluster.tf line 47, in resource "helm_release" "ingress":
│   47: resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
```

If the ingress policy file is needed here, this is the file content:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:GetCoipPoolUsage",
                "ec2:DescribeCoipPools",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "acm:DescribeCertificate",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
                "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
                "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACLForResource",
                "wafv2:AssociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:DisassociateWebACL",
                "shield:GetSubscriptionState",
                "shield:DescribeProtection",
                "shield:CreateProtection",
                "shield:DeleteProtection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateSecurityGroup"
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/app/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebAcl",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
  }
```

I tried to refresh the `aws_eks_cluster_auth` object manually (`terraform refrsh`) but it did not help. I also tried to use `exec` within the `helm.kubernetes` provider instead of providing `token` key - did not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.